# communication between Matlab and external application (C++)

Tags: c++, matlab, udp, communication, mex

I am trying to connect C++ open-source library related to graphics, which is called openFrameworks, to Matlab/Simlink.

What I want to do is to visualize certain features with that graphic application after signal processing using Matlab. So in Simlink S-Function, recording biosignals (e.g., EEG) is successively conducted and calculation for extracting certain features takes place online. I would like to pass these features' values to openFrameworks. Then it visualizes as designed in C++ codes I have written.

I thought that would be possible if I could make MEX and call it within Matlab script. I made it and actually it ran. However, openFrameworks is designed to continue updating graphics forever until I end the application. So after calling MEX, MEX was running constantly and I could not return to Matlab. Maybe sending features from Matlab to MEX online and updating graphics seem difficult When I use MEX.

Are there any good ways of communication between these two? If MEX makes it possible, I will continue working on MEX. I think running Matlab/Simlink and openFrameworks parallelly and sending necessary data from Matlab to openFrameworks using UDP is a good way.

I would like you to give me your opinion. I don't know UDP is the right way since I have never work on the programs sending data between applications. If that is the case, I am happy. If my idea is wrong, please  correct me in terms of both of MEX and UDP.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you send data to openFrameWorks from mex file? You should keep that connection alive using persistent data (mexMakeArrayPersistent or static). You should then return from mex file as soon as you send data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention UDP, the best solution probably to use the free TCP/UPD/IP Toolbox from the [MATLAB Central File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/345-tcp-udp-ip-toolbox-2-0-6).  It allows UDP communication directly from MATLAB.  It is implemented via a MEX file, much as you are considering.

So your solution would involve encoding the data you want into a buffer, then transmitting it using this toolbox.  On the other side, you'd need to build your visualizer into a standalone application with a listening UDP socket.

Remember that UDP is not guaranteed.  If your visualizer will work fine if it it occasionally misses a packet, UDP is exactly the correct choice!  If not, you might want to use TCP instead.  TCP is stream-oriented, so you'd have to make your own packet structure to separate your units of data.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of suggesting bad coding practice -- if you are developing a project only for your own prototyping and research use (not for external deployment), and this is a one-off event, the simplest solution may be to write to an external file (e.g. using MATLAB's `dlmwrite`) and to listen for the file in a C++ application (e.g. using `ifstream` in a while loop).

There are a couple of problems with this approach (it certainly is not the highest performance), and sockets are certainly the "right" way to do this, but the point of MATLAB is usually to get something working as quickly as possible and file I/O is something that doesn't require esoteric knowledge.